# If Workbook gets closed then clear range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code which clears a specific range in the target worksheet when the workbook gets closed. I tried the two codes below, none of them worked for me. Anyone an idea?

```
Sub VergleichLeeren()

If Workbooks("Jira & DEFTEP Vergleich").Close Then
Worksheets("Vergleich 1").Range("M5").Clear

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

 Worksheets("Vergleich 1").Range("M5").Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: If `Workbook_BeforeClose` is placed in  `ThisWorkbook` / `DieseArbeitsmappe` module (under Microsoft Excel Objects), range M5 should be cleared

Comment: First code is strange and it can only raise an error, but what about the second one? As asked in the above comment, where this event code is placed? If it is in `ThisWorkbook`, maybe the events are disabled. In such a case, you should place such a code line in a testing Sub: `Application.EnableEvents = True`. Place a break on `Worksheets("Vergleich 1").Range("M5").Clear` and try closing. Anyhow, in order to see that the range has been cleared, **you must add `ThisWorkbook.Save`**...

Comment: Top, fixed it :) I placed it in a module and not in ThisWorkbook. Thank you both!